# different way to find a name to iterator

Tags: c

After writing so many for loop, I could not find to name iterator. I want write meaningful iterator' name, can you help me ?

ex ;

- i
- j
- ii
- jj
- iii
- jjj

  usage :

  for i = 0 ; i < ...
      for j = 0 j < ...

Finding new iterator name makes my life a bit miserable. How do you find name to your iterator ?

Comment: Maybe you should try finding a better algorithm or refactor your code so that you don't have to write so many nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want write meaningful iterator' name

Then the name you use should reflect the meaning of what the iterator is used for.

For example if you are looping over products inside a loop of categories inside a loop of catgegory-groups, you might use names like `producti`, `categoryi`, `groupi`, perhaps together with number-of-item names likes `productn`/`categoryn`/`groupn` and/or array names like `products`/`categories`/`groups`.

I'd only use `i` for the simplest short non-nested loops that one can understand with a quick glance. Personally I wouldn't even use `j`; when loops are nested that usually calls for more self-explanatory variable names.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more then 3 nested loops in the same function, this is a [code-smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

You should probably [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) your code [move some staff into other functions, and use these functions].

i,j,k should be enough for most functions.

Answer (score 2):

Try to have meaningful variable names, e.g. `int RowNumber`, `int ColumnNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

loop indexes are not limited to 1 or 2 character names. try using a fully describing name, like `current_element`, `inner_iterator`, ...

the name should describe what you are indexing, but also tell the purpose of the loop.